# Microsoft Access 2010 filtering data based on tempvar

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

i have a web database and im trying to filter a datasheet, based on the contents of a tempvar. Im trying to use the record source property of the datasheet to do this.

I need to do this because, every employee that logs in should only be able to see a given subset of data in the products table. In the employee table, i have an extra column with a string value which is the data that particular employee should see.

I have a login form that on clicking login, adds this string to the tempvars collection.I can see the tempvar has been added in the immediate window as shown below:

```
?tempvars!tmpgrpdsc -> "IAMS"
```

i use the query builder option to complete the record source property as shown below.

**The problem is, nothing is returned !**

But when i enter the string "IAMS", i get records returned.

[image: Query window showing criteria]

> **However, i have done this with another datasheet and it has worked, the tempvar here held a number ! See below:**

[image: Orders data sheet]

What am i missing or is there a better way to filter records based on the login. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you showed should work.
However, have you tried to change the criteria to `="""" & [Tempvars]![tmpGrdsc] & """"`

Also, to make sure that your tempvar is actually containing the data during the query, you could show it as a field, just to check exactly what data is being returned during the query:

```
SELECT Orders.*,
       [Tempvars]![tmpGrdsc] AS TmpGrdsc
FROM Orders
```

Comment: Hi Renaud, thanks for your contribution. i tried this but it still came up blank. i did some testing and it appears the query cannot be filtered if the tempvar contains a string (?). So i tried replacing the tempvar with the actual string it contained ("IAMS" in this case) and the filter worked which was strange. But i need to use a variable to make the filter dynamic. The tempvar that contained the employeeID which is a number as shown above worked ! Has anyone observed something similar? thanks

Comment: This is a very old question. Mentioning in case someone else gets side tracked. My TempVars containing strings do work in similar set up. There were other issues I had to fix. It's been over 8 years, perhaps TempVars holding strings didn't work for queries' filter criteria before.