# MS Access 2010 query using tempvar inside IN() condition

Tags: ms-access, macros, ms-access-2010

I am trying to filter a query using a temporary variable that is inside an `IN()` condition. The temporary variable contains a list of text values. I am using the macro-builder tool in Access 2010.

Assume I have a query `qryMain` that produces:

```
Field1 Field2
1      A
4      B
2      C
3      D
```

without a `WHERE` clause. Using the clause

`WHERE [tblMain].[Field2] IN([TempVars]![tmpField2])`

to filter the query, the desired results are

```
Field1 Field2
1      A
4      B
```

when `tmpField2` is set to `"A,B"`. I set `tmpField2` using an on-click event in form `frmMain` using SetTempVar and Requery the subform/subreport object `sfrmMain` that is based on `qryMain`. This is done via the MS macro-builder, not VBA.

Unfortunately, requerying `sfrmMain` produces an empty table rather than the expected results. Note that if I set `tmpField2` to `"A"`, then the requery macro works as expected.

I have tried multiple variations of initializing `tmpField2`, based on Access's [double quote requirements](http://allenbrowne.com/casu-17.html), but still no success. My question is similar to this as-yet unanswered [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27186465/microsoft-access-2010-filtering-data-based-on-tempvar), but my question involves passing the temp variable inside an `IN()` statement within the `WHERE` clause, without using VBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not actually due to `TempVars`.  If your value list came from a form's text box instead of `TempVars`, the result would be the same.

For what you're attempting to do, `IN ()` requires a hard-coded list of values:

```sql
SELECT m.Field1, m.Field2
FROM tblMain AS m
WHERE m.Field2 IN ('A','B');
```

But, instead of a hard-coded list of values, you want to supply the list dynamically when the query is run:

```sql
WHERE m.Field2 IN (something_dynamic);
```

Unfortunately, Access will not cooperate.  Whatever you supply for *something_dynamic*, Access will interpret it to be only one value ... **not** a list of values.  And it doesn't matter what method you use to supply *something_dynamic* ... a `TempVar`, a text box, a formal query parameter, a custom VBA function which returns a string containing a list of values ... that list will be evaluated as only a single value.

If you were willing to use VBA, you could write the query at runtime to include a hard-coded value list before executing it.  Since you want to avoid VBA, you can try something like this ...

```vb
WHERE InStr(1, [TempVars]![tmpField2], "'" & m.Field2 & "'") > 0
```

Note that approach requires quoting text values within *tmpField2*: *'A','B'*

Also beware that approach could be painfully slow with a large table.  Access would need to evaluate that `InStr` expression for every row in the table.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that this is not a syntax issue, but that I'm using the wrong approach. I changed my approach and solved my problem by simply passing the multiple temp variables (ie, not in list form) to the `IN()` portion.    

I started down the (unsuccessful) path of using my temp variables to contain a list, because at one time I was specifying the `WHERE()` content via the macro-builder. However, that environment limits the user to 255 characters, and I had a lot of temp variables. Hence the idea to aggregate temp variables into a concatenated list, which Access didn't like.

Comment: Mark, if you know you only ever have 2 values you method is fine. @Hans.  I agree although I think I would recommend using   the following which may be a little quicker and you method might match ",dog," with ",doggie,"

WHERE "*," & m.Field2 & ",*" LIKE [TempVars]![tmpField2]

TempVars is assumed to be comma separated